# How to setup tomcat with intelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea

I used to use eclipse for my java project till now. In that I used to give a server.xml corresponding to a tomcat server. But in IntelliJ I can't find where should I give that server.xml. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this file in [Directories Used by IntelliJ IDEA to Store Settings, Caches, Plugins and Logs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/directories-used-by-intellij-idea-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html?origin=old_help).

For my computer, I am using window 10, I found that in following path:

```
C:\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\<project name>\conf\server.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, you should click on Run > Edit configurations... > Add new configuration (clicking on "+" icon) > Tomcat (select local or remote) and complete the configuration using your settings.
I hope this can help you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Goto File, then New Project.

Create from Scratch.

Click Next, give the Project a Name, and keep Clicking Next until the Desired Technologies window comes.

Click Web-Application, then Finish.

Click File, then Settings.

Click on Application Servers and Hit the + to add a new Tomcat Server.

Set the Home Directory of the application server you have just installed(ex: c:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation// and then Click ok.

Click on the run button, and then then Edit Defaults.

Click on the + in the top left hand corner and add a Tomcat Server, then Local configuration.

Select the Tomcat in the pulldown menu next to Application Server.

I hope this will help you.